# Should I use radio buttons here?

Tags: radio-buttons, radio

So this is an interview software where we define the interview rounds (the number of rounds and the name of these rounds) while creating a job.

Now for creating a new interview we select the job and candidate first, (note: one candidate can be interviewed for multiple jobs), & the next step is to select the interview round which is the difficult part.

Lets take Job A for example. Job A has 3 rounds.
The candidate already completed round 1.
SO now we have 2 rounds to select from. But round 3 will be disabled until round 2 is completed. Round 2 will have 'Skip the round button' which if clicked round 2 will be disabled & round 3 can be clicked. I have in mind something like this:

[image]

But adding a button in the card doesnt seem to be a very good idea. Also what else might we use here if not radio buttons?
I'm sure there is a better way to solve this, would like to hear your ideas.

Comment: It doesn't really feel like the radio button concept fits with this scenario, because (if I'm reading it correctly) you can't actually pick a radio button - there's only ever one option available to pick at each time (previous rounds are disabled, and future rounds also disabled, so you can only pick the 'now' option). I think your issue isn't actually the 'buttons within radio buttons' one you think it is, it's actually 'should I use radio-buttons here'.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have edited the question. So the question is what might we use here. We need to display the other rounds along with the current round.

Comment: Have you considered using dropdown menu to select which round it is?

Comment: Hi yes but the problem is adding a button inside the dropdown to skip the current rounds seems to be much more complex

Comment: @Bluekafka please help me understand why would an interviewer want to skip an interview round _while creating a new interview_? Is there a way to do skip an interview round elsewhere in the system?

Comment: Hi this is just a backup option in the rare cases when an interviewer might want to skip a round for eg: the interviewer for that round is not available and they want to skip to the next round. There is no option to skip interviews anywhere else in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with buttons:

- <kbd>Select</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd> as main
- <kbd>Select</kbd> button with the toggle status between <kbd>In process</kbd> and <kbd>Done</kbd> automatic as the processes are fulfilled or manual

[image]

Comment: Wow never thought of it like this! Thanks for your insight! This might actually work. Eliminating the radio element and keeping buttons instead. Only thing is the next page is where we setup the interview (scheduling & etc) and then the interview status changes to 'In progress' & other statuses automatically which we can view in the particular interview page (which also has buttons like "mark interview as completed' adding evaluation and everything else). But we can use the other aspects of this design.